# MySQL syntax error when specifying innodb database type and character set

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I cant seem to import my tables.sql to a database called callumba_login. Here is the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Country(
    country_code                char(2) not null,
    country_name                varchar(60) not null,
    primary key(country_code)
    )type=innodb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

MySQL says:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `type=innodb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8    COLLATE utf8_general_ci` at line 5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message points you directly to the bad syntax.

`type=innodb` should be `engine=innodb`.